# Display content based on URL path

Tags: views, 8

Creating a view block for a specific content type  (for example, *gallery*) how can I filter it so that the view only shows gallery node that live under a certain path (for example, /business/gallery/christmas and /business/gallery/luncheon)?

I've tried to play around with contextual filters (using ID with various setting) and adding an ID filter criteria with no success.

What should I use to filter this?